# (React.js) Scroll through list using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, autocomplete, arrow-keys

I'm developing an autocomplete component, but I'm not able to scroll with the arrow keys (down/up), with the mouse it works normally.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9zJZ.png)

I've researched a lot about it and tried to solve this problem with refs, but it didn't work.

```
const refs = filteredSuggestions.reduce((acc, value) => {
  acc[value.id] = React.createRef();
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Place where it is referenced

```
suggestionsListComponent = (
   <ul class="suggestions">
        {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
          let className;
          if (index === activeSuggestion) {
            className = "suggestion-active";
          }
          return (
            <li ref={refs[suggestion.id]} className={className} key={suggestion} onClick={onClick}>
              {suggestion}
            </li>
          );
        })}
   </ul>
);
```

The complete code is here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-autocomplete-564vd)

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Easily integrate your react component with keyboard arrow keys, with the same configuration used in [swipe-react](https://github.com/leon-good-life/swipe-react) and [wheel-react](https://github.com/leon-good-life/wheel-react) packages.

**Usage**

1. Install the npm package:

   ```
   npm install --save arrow-keys-react
   ```
2. Import it:

   ```
   import ArrowKeysReact from 'arrow-keys-react';
   ```
3. Config arrow keys events ('left', 'right', 'up', 'down'), at least one of them, in your component constructor, or in render function:

   ```
   ArrowKeysReact.config({
     left: () => {
      console.log('left key detected.');
    },
    right: () => {
      console.log('right key detected.');
    },
    up: () => {
      console.log('up key detected.');
    },
    down: () => {
      console.log('down key detected.');
    }
   });
   ```

4.Integrate with your React component:

```
<YourComponent {...ArrowKeysReact.events} />
```

**Example**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ArrowKeysReact from 'arrow-keys-react';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   content: 'Use arrow keys on your keyboard!'
 };
 ArrowKeysReact.config({
  left: () => {
    this.setState({
      content: 'left key detected.'
    });
  },
  right: () => {
    this.setState({
      content: 'right key detected.'
    });
  },
  up: () => {
    this.setState({
      content: 'up key detected.'
    });
  },
  down: () => {
    this.setState({
      content: 'down key detected.'
    });
  }
 });
}
render() {
return (
  <div {...ArrowKeysReact.events} tabIndex="1">
    {this.state.content}
  </div>
  );
  }
 }

export default App;
```

**Remarks**

- When you use `div`, add `tabIndex` property.
- The element must be on focus in order to detect arrow keys. The arrow keys will be detected when the user will click on the element, or focus it using the tab key in the keyboard. Alternatively, you can program your component to `focus()` when it loaded.
- `ArrowKeysReact.config` can be placed in `render` function instead of in the `constructor` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is not about the reaction of arrow keys, but about the fact that when you press keyboard arrow keys, the scroll doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok. I founded this, and hope helpful for you.

https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/autocompletes